# Interrupting execution of handler/timer if user input occurs Android

Tags: android, timer, handler, delayed-job

I am trying to make feature that will display text on screen and after few sec to disappear. I have managed that with `Handler` and `Timer` classes.

The problem is that I need to somehow stop executing these timers if user makes input over keyboard before timer's time pass and rerun timer again to display different data.

I am facing with problem that the view has remaining visible after user input and disappears after 1-2 sec instead after 5 sec.

the codes that I have used:

```
 //do something

final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something again
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

AND

```
//do something
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this code will be executed after 5 seconds
                //do something again
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

THanks

Answer (score 1):

For timer you can use `timer.cancel();` and for handler you can use `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);`
So just declare a Runnable runnable as a global variable, then instantiate it as below

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something again
            }
        }, 5000);
```

this is the runnable you will pass when you removeCallbacks. Similarly you can use this `handler.removeCallbacks(null);` this will stop all the handlers that have been declared. I would suggest that you declare both the handler and the timer as global variables and only instatntiate them when you are calling the timer tasks.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you have saved my hair :D